# How do you scan in n number of words from a file at a time?

Tags: java, file

I have a really large file of text (1 million words+) and am trying to read it in in sections to avoid excessive memory usage and to try to speed it up. I am trying to read in 10k words at a time, place the unique words in that section in an array, and read the next 10k to do the same. 
I have worked out this so far:

```
while(scn.hasNext) {                       // Check if there is anything in the file
    for(int i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {       // For the next 10000 strings,
        if(scn.hasNext) {                  // as long as the file doesnt end,
            fullBook.add(scn.next());      // add the word to the string I am working on.
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

All of this would be encased in yet another while so that I can work with each string before reading in the next 10k. I figure there is a faster way, but I haven't found it yet. I have looked through Scanner and Buffered reader to see if I could find a method that would only do so many words but I keep coming up empty. I don't mind learning a new method in order to do this or just some trick to speed it up. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: so what is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: Are you just want to read in everything and add them to `List<String>`?

Comment: Try coding a ```Thread``` or ```Runnable``` class that can take a range of words. Then just divide up all the words across threads, each thread works in parallel. Listen for all the threads to complete, then process the result data.

Comment: I would like to get the timing below O(n^2) if at all possible

Comment: @wdavies973 can you give me an example? I have never heard of thread or runnable yet so I am reading up on it now

Comment: @MichaelDevries, even you are using 2 loops, your method is not O(n^2), but is O(n). It only scans your file once, not twice.

Comment: Why do you think time complexity is _O(n^2)_ right now? If it is, it's in code you haven't shown, because the shown code is _O(n)_.

Comment: I see! I was mistaken. You are correct. I was assuming that each loop would read through the datafile each time.

Comment: How do you construct your `Scanner`?

Comment: String fileLocation = location.next();  

    Scanner scn = new Scanner (new FileReader(fileLocation));

Comment: So, what's wrong with your approach and what is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I was looking for a faster way of completing the same task. It was more a question of how to improve than a problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is without difference from the below code in single loop.

```
while (scn.hasNext()) {
    fullBook.add(scn.next());
```

In fact, it is not meaningful to do in using 2 loops. The buffer of the `Scanner` is not changed and is always 1024. You may see it in the source of `Scanner`.

As the speed of I/O is slow, you may want to increase the buffer size and read from file with less frequency. You may change the creation of your 
`Scanner` with below code instead.

```
// Create a buffered reader with 1M buffer
Scanner scn = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileLocation), 1048576));
```

Comment: Nice! I knew you could play with the buffer in my IDE but I didn't know you could do it in the code itself!

Comment: I think _"the buffer in your IDE"_ means the heap size of your application. It just reserves memory for your program execution. How to use the reserved memory always depends on your coding, e.g. specifying a larger buffer size in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Let me know if there is  a better way to do this.

Note: Scanner is NOT thread safe, @Alex recommends using a `RandomAccessFile` to bypasst his issue.

Use a `Thread` like

```
public class Parser implements UnitParserListener {


public Parser() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i += 10_000) {
        new UnitParser(scanner, this, i);
    }
}

public void unitCompleted(int startCount, String[] words) {
    // This method will be called once for each thread completion
}

private class UnitParser implements Runnable {

    private UnitParserListener listener;
    private Thread thread;
    private int startCount;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public UnitParser(Scanner scanner, UnitParserListener listener, int startCount) {
        this.scanner = scanner.
        // Start the thread
        this.startCount = startCount;
        this.listener = listener;

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        // You'll have to edit this to your liking
        while(scn.hasNext()) {                       // Check if there is anything in the file
            for(int i = startCount; i < startCount + 10_000; i++) {

            }
        }

        // Thread complete
        listener.unitCompleted(startCount, results);

        // Attempt to stop the thread
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

}

}
interface UnitParserListener {
    // startCount will give us a way to identify the thread
    void unitCompleted(int startCount, String[] words);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I will have to try this out. Thanks for the information!

Comment: You are using different `Scanner` in each `Thread`. How to read in the same file?

Comment: That's a good point, I just edited the code so the scanner reference gets passed in.

Comment: Using multi-thread is not impossible, but you need to use `RandomAccessFile` in each `Thread` and start to read in the file in different potion, which will complicate the whole thing at all.